# How to aggregate all array values of multiple records in Postgres array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table full of records and an array column, and now I want to get a list of all (unique) values in that column. What's the best way of getting that?

I tried playing around with `unnest`, `array_agg` and `string_agg` but didn't get anywhere...

(using Postgres 9.2)

Comment: Updated answer after rereading you question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select distinct unnest(a)
from (values
    (array[1, 2]),
    (array[2, 3])
) s(a);
 unnest 
--------
      3
      1
      2
```

Or aggregated in an array:

```
select array_agg(a order by a)
from (
    select distinct unnest(a) as a
    from (values
        (array[1, 2]),
        (array[2, 3])
    ) s(a)
) s;
 array_agg 
-----------
 {1,2,3}
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this in one go or without a subquery?

Comment: @Manuel Not without creating an special aggregate function.

Comment: I looked at your first version and actually that is what I need (one row per result). Could you update your post once more and include both versions, for future readers? Thanks!